# Grouping the data with pandas TimeGrouper with interval between 5 to 25 min, 25 to 45 min, 45 to 05 minutes

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python pandas and I am trying to group my data on 20 Minute interval. If I use `Data.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('20Min'))` it is working but it is giving the grouped data from 0 to 20 min, 20-40 etc. But I want to group my data between 5 to 25 min, 25 to 45 min etc.

Can you help how to achieve this pandas TimeGrouper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Data.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='20Min',base=5, label='right')
```

will give you data grouped by 20 Min, starting with forward 5 min (since we are using **base as 5** and **label as right**. i.e, it will be grouped as 05 to 25, 25 to 45 etc. and if you use this:

```
Data.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='20Min',base=55, label='left')
```

will give you data grouped by 20 Min with backward 5 min (i.e, your data will group as :55 to :15, :15 to :35 etc)